# How to to store a audio file for an Asp.net MVC website hosted by Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, file-storage

I'm not really a website developer but I have developed a website for a course.
In this site i'm using an API in which I make a request and I get back a mp3file. This file a want to store somewhere so the website can play it when the user presses a button. When I had the site locally on my computer I just did it like this:

```
client.DownloadFile(url, @"C:\Users\tidus89\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MetalNames2\MetalNames2\Downloads\bandName.mp3");
```

This worked like a charm! But when I published the website to Azure I got the error "Access to the path '....' is denied".

So I did some searching and tried to use:

```
client.DownloadFile(url, @"~/App_Data/bandName.mp3");
```

But that gives me the error "Access to the path 'D:\Windows\system32\~\App_Data\bandName.mp3' is denied."

Does anybody have an idea?

/tidus89

Comment: You have to use `Server.MapPath()` to resolve the ~

Comment: How do I use that?

Comment: It seems this is permission issue. Have you try to give full permission to your folder?

Comment: I don't know...what needs the permission? I mean, what is the difference in having the website locally and try to access the folder (this works) vs having the website on Azure and try to access the folder (doesn't work)?

Answer (score 0):

For hosting audio / video files, your best bet may be to use blob storage. I do that for my podcast files, and illustrate exactly how to do that [in a tutorial.](http://www.davevoyles.com/using-blob-storage-to-host-my-podcast-mp3-files/)

It's very straight forward. Essentially you upload your files to blob, then make a simple request to the URL that the file is stored at, and it plays back.

Comment: This sounds like it works the same way as I am doing (just that I am doing it on my own computer). And it's probably what I need! I will look into it when I've got the time, thanks!

Comment: I used to store mp3 and mp4 files in the same root directory where I was serving my web content and ran into a bunch of issues with serving the content.

I wound up just offloading it all to blob storage in Azure for a couple of reasons:
1) Crazy cheap
2) Serves it quickly

If there is a roadblock in streaming audio / video, I've probably hit it at this point.
I ported the Sega CD game to HTML5 and serve all of the FMV (videos) via blog storage in the browser. You can see it here: http://www.davevoyles.com/?s=night+trap